# Reading the actual file creation date on Mac OS with Perl

Tags: macos, perl, file

I would like to read the creation date of a file as it is represented on the Mac OS Finder.  This is part of my code:

```
require File::stat;
use Time::localtime;

($dev, $ino, $mode, $nlink, $uid, $gid, $rdev, $size, $atime, $mtime, $ctime, $blksize, $blocks) = stat($file_path);
print ctime($ctime) . "\n";
```

On the Finder, every file has two dates: created and modified.  I assumed that `$ctime` would be equal to the "created" date from the Finder, but it is completely different.  Doing some research, I found out that most Unix operating systems don't store this kind of date, however, Mac OS does.

Does anybody know a way to read this information from a file?

Comment: ctime is last change, not creation

Comment: @stark `mtime` is the last modification time. `ctime` is last `inode change time`. (atime last access). ctime is many times the file creation time (e.g. when after the creation is not modified the inode)

Comment: You could try binding to [`stat()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man2/stat.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/stat) using some sort of FFI and grabbing the `st_birthtimespec` field.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply read the output from the `mdls` command. You can always do something like:

```
perl -e '@lines = qx(mdls filename.txt); print "@lines[3]";'
```

or similar.

see `man mdls`

```
 mdls -- lists the metadata attributes for the specified file
```

for creation date you should use:

```
mdls -raw -name kMDItemFSCreationDate filename
```

Ps: the module [MacOSX::File::Catalog](http://search.cpan.org/~dankogai/MacOSX-File-0.71/Catalog/Catalog.pm) is developed for this, but unfortunately it is broken in Mountain Lion. (error during install - at least on my OS X)

Comment: It works pretty well, however, I would like to share a performance comment: compared with the use of `File::stat`, this method is **incredibly slow**.

Comment: @calvillo Of course - youre forking a new process every time - it is really slow. Unfortunately, the `MacOSX::File::Catalog` doesn't compiles, and the `File::Stat` doesn't return you the OS X's File creation date. It is OS X extension, what File::Stat doesn't covers (has only ctime, mtime, atime).

Comment: Yes... that sucks.  Do you know where OS X stores this additional information?  Is that within each file?  Or in separate file or database?

Answer (score 4):

The problem with the `mdls` command is that its time output is not in UNIX timestamps. Try instead the `stat` command, with Mac-specific features:

```
stat -f %B _filename_
```

In perl:

```
$_="filename"
print scalar localtime `stat -f %B $_`
```

Comment: This is much more convenient than the accepted answer (since a Unix timestamp is returned), and probably faster, too, if one is only interested in the creation date.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I also wanted to note that this will work for all files & directories in a single directory by simply appending an asterisk like so `directory/*`